# Control or split the target and value before & after `:` in string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've created a script that returns duplicated lines in CSS by Javascript

```
//main.js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], (err, data) =>  {
    if (err) throw err;
    let convertedFileToObject = Object;
    let spaceRemover = Object;
    let findDuplicates = Function;
    convertedFileToObject = data.toString().split('\n');
    spaceRemover = convertedFileToObject.map(post => post.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('.', '').replace(';', '').replace('img', '').replace('span', '').replace('from', '').replace(/\s+/g, '')).filter(i => i);
    findDuplicates = (arr) => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) != index);
    console.log(findDuplicates(spaceRemover).length > 0 ? findDuplicates(spaceRemover) : 'Congrats you don\'t have any duplicate')
});
```

CSS Test

```
/*app.css*/
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #282c34;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

in terminal

```
$ node main.js app.css
[ 'background-color:#282c34', 'display:flex' ] // the result
```

How to control before `:` and after `:` to make it one object, to be expected output

```
$ node main.js app.css
[ {'background-color': '#282c34'}, {'display': 'flex'} ] // the expected
```

or remove the text whatever it's before `:`

```
$ node main.js app.css
[ '#282c34', 'flex' ] // the another expected
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split between key and value and return as an object.

```
... 
findDuplicates = ... your original code... 
const dupes = findDuplicates(spaceRemover);
const result = dupes.map((item) => {
    splitted = item.split(':')
    return { [splitted[0]]: splitted[1].trim() };
});
console.log(result.length > 0 ? result : 'Congrats you don\'t have any duplicate')
```

Answer (score 3):

After you filter down to your `findDuplicates` array, you can `map` that into a list of objects:

```
findDupObjects = findDuplicates.map((s) =>
{
    let keyVal = s.split(':')
    let key = keyVal[0]
    let value = keyVal[1]
    var obj = {}
    obj[key] = value
    return obj
}); // <= [ {background-color: '#282c34'}, {display: 'flex'} ]
```